# Is it possible to get a single list of descendants that are either "Teaching" or "Teaching2"

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Take this code:

```
XDocument docAssignHistory = XDocument.Load(strHistoryDatabase);

var listHistory = docAssignHistory.Descendants("Teaching");
var listHistory2 = docAssignHistory.Descendants("Teaching2");
```

Is it possible to get a single list of descendants that are either "Teaching" or "Teaching2" ?

Comment: The linked duplicate shows a general-purpose `.Union()`.  While that will work, I think it would be easier to do `docAssignHistory.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name == "Teaching" || e.Name == "Teaching2")`.

Comment: @dbc My full code line: `var listHistory = docAssignHistory.Descendants("Teaching").Union(docAssignHistory.Descendants("Teaching2")).Where(x => ConvertWeekNameToDate(x.Parent.Name.ToString()) > datWeekOfMeeting);`.

Comment: @dbc Can it be simplified to not use `Union`?

Comment: `Union()` will work of course, but it will be computationally more expensive because internally it requires building a hash table for the second enumerable to cross-reference it with the first.  This is roughly `n log(n)`.  If you check for both names in a `Where()` clause performance will be linear.  That's what I meant by "easier".

Comment: Also, and I am not sure about this, I suspect that `.Union()` may not return in document order.  If you need the union to be in document order you will need to use [`.InDocumentOrder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.extensions.indocumentorder?view=net-7.0) which adds an additional computational step.

Comment: @dbc Can my snippet be changed as you suggested ?

Comment: I think `docAssignHistory.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name == "Teaching" || e.Name == "Teaching2").Where(x => ConvertWeekNameToDate(x.Parent.Name.ToString()) > datWeekOfMeeting);` should work.

Comment: @dbc Work fine and IMHO should be the accepted answer for my question.